# Splitting a String by parentheses, grouping with parentheses, java

Tags: java, regex

I've looked through most of the regex questions here, and none match my particular case.

Say I have a string: `"ABe(CD)(EF)GHi"`

I want: `"A", "Be", "(CD)", "(EF)", "G", "Hi"`

I have tried:

```
.split("(?=[A-Z\\(\\)])"), which gives me: "A", "Be", "(", "C", "D", ")", "(", "E", "F", ")", "G", "Hi".
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
String input = "ABe(CD)(EF)GHi";

String[] split = input.split("(?=[A-Z](?![^(]*\\)))|(?=\\()|(?<=\\))");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(split));
```

*Output*

```
[A, Be, (CD), (EF), G, Hi]
```

*Explained*

```
 (?=              Before:
    [A-Z]           Uppercase letter
    (?![^(]*\))       not followed by ')' without first seeing a '('
                      i.e. not between '(' and ')'
 )
|(?=              or before:
    \(              '('
 )
|(?<=             or after:
     \)             ')'
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
String array = "ABe(CD)(EF)GHi";
int i = 0;

for(int j=0; j<array.length();)
{
   if(Character.isUpperCase(array.charAt(i)))
   {
       j++;
       System.out.println(array.substring(i, i+1));
      if(Character.isUpperCase(array.charAt(i+1)))
      {   System.out.println(array.substring(i+1, i+3));
          i = i+3;
          j = j + 3;
      }
  }
  else
  {
      System.out.println(array.substring(i+1, i+3));
      i = i+4;
      j = j + 3;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do matching instead of splitting.

```
String s = "ABe(CD)(EF)GHi";
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\([^()]*\)|[A-Z][a-z]+|[A-Z]");
Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(s);
while(matcher.find()){
        System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
}
```

[DEMO](https://www.regex101.com/r/NulVGi/1)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew someone closed the same question as dupe :-)