# Regex for ignoring inner parentheses when grouping by parentheses, java

Tags: java, regex

For reference, this was my [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41437068/splitting-a-string-by-parentheses-grouping-with-parentheses-java). 
Originally I had a string: `"ABe(CD)(EF)GHi"`

I wanted: `"A", "Be", "(CD)", "(EF)", "G", "Hi"`

Two solutions worked for me:

```
String[] split = input.split("(?=[A-Z](?![^(]*\\)))|(?=\\()|(?<=\\))");
```

and

```
String s = "ABe(CD)(EF)GHi";
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\([^()]*\)|[A-Z][a-z]+|[A-Z]");
Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(s);
while(matcher.find()){
        System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
}
```

However, I have a new string now: `"ABe(C(CD)D)(EF)GHi"`

and I want `"A", "Be", "(C(CD)D)", "(EF)", "G", "Hi"`

Is there a simple modification I can do from either provided solution to get the intended result?

Also, if I should not have posted a new question for this topic, I apologize; I'm new.

Comment: No, Java regex does not support arbitrary number of nested parentheses, as it does not support recursion. If there is only 1 level of nesting, you may fix it with regex.

Comment: So this problem cannot be solved by Regex?

Comment: Pretty much by definition, kind of. A regex is an expression in a regular language, which is one that can be executed with a finite number of states. If you're doing something like maintaining a counter, that introduces (effectively) infinite states: at least one per value of the counter. The reason I said "kind of" is that many regex languages, including Java's, are _not_ strictly regular. But even so, I don't think what you want can be done... or if it can be, the resulting regex will be more complicated than doing it another way.

Comment: Thank you. I will explore character by character parsing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, It may be long but works as you expect

```
(?=[A-z][a-z])[A-Z][a-z]|[A-z]|\(.*?\)(?:[A-Z]\))?
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, as discussed above, I'm looking for a recursive solution with multiple nested parentheses, and that's not possible with regex apparently. But thank you anyways! This works for one-level nests.

Comment: In Java recursive(**nested matches**) looping is not possible yet, whereas in PHP, perl, .Net, it is possible